# ¿Como puedo pasar el siguiente código a mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
Create table tblResetPasswordRequests
(
 Id UniqueIdentifier Primary key,
 UserId int Foreign key references tblUsers(Id),
 ResetRequestDateTime DateTime
)
```

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo leer la sección [ask], preguntas de calidad obtienen respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con esto:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblResetPasswordRequests` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  `ResetRequestDateTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aaa_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES `tblUsers` (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Si no quieres que el id se autoincremental, entonces solo quita "AUTO_INCREMENT".